# Method within Do While statement in Java?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I know this will be really basic for anyone who actually knows Java, but I'm still learning. I'm doing an exercise where I have to create a method 'startGuessing()' that uses another method 'guess()', displaying the output of that method to the terminal. In addition, it displays how many attempts it took, and ends when the correct number is guessed.

I'm find with the number of attempts, and ending when the correct number is guessed - but I can't for the life of me get my head around how to use the output of the inner method. I'm new to Java, so I'm trying to actually understand as opposed to just having the answer on a plate. The below is my code (it's the startGuessing() method that I can't figure out logic for:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HiLo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startGuessing();
    }


    
    static int random;
    
    public void generateNumber() 
    {
       //The following lines generate and output a random number between 1 and 10
        random = (int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
    }





   //Write the guess() method below 
   public void guess()
   {

       //Create a new scanner object to receive user input
          Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter your guess ");
        int guess = sc.nextInt();
          if(guess == random)
          {
              System.out.println("Hit!");

          } else if(guess < random)
          {
              System.out.println("Low!");

          } else if(guess > random)
          {
              System.out.println("High!");

          }
          



   }


    public void startGuessing()

    {
        int i = 0;

        do {
            guess();
            i++;
        }

        while(guess != random);
        System.out.println("That took you " + i + " guesses!");
    }



    }
```

I know this will be really basic for anyone who knows Java, but I'm just starting out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `public String guess()`

Comment: Thanks for this, though if guess were a string, I wouldn't be able to compare it to random, which is an int? I'm still playing around with possibilities. Also, not sure why someone marked my question down - but oh well

Comment: I was referring to the method declaration and not the variable

Comment: Hey all, so in the end I ended up taking the code from the inner method guess(), altering it and just using that within a do while loop, and it seemed to work.

Comment: Wasn’t it part of the requirement to have a method `guess()`? Why not learn how to write a method that returns a string?

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need to do. I've had a play around, and learned how to do that. Now the only thing is figuring out how to use this string to evaluate a condition in a Do While Loop that houses this method

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end. Taking the code from the guess() method, altering it with a boolean flag, and using that within the do while loop:

```
 public static void startGuessing2() {
        boolean correct = false;
        int i = 1;
        do {


            //Create a new scanner object to receive user input
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter your guess ");
            int guess = sc.nextInt();

            if (guess == random) {
                System.out.println("Hit!");
                correct = true;

            } else if (guess < random) {
                System.out.println("Low!");
                correct = false;

            } else if (guess > random) {
                System.out.println("High!");
                correct = false;

            }
            i++;
        } while (correct == false);
        System.out.println("That took you " + i + " guesses!");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is where I've got to with actually learning to write a method that returns a string:

```
//Write the guess() method below
    public static String guess() {

        //Create a new scanner object to receive user input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your guess ");
        int guessVal = sc.nextInt();

        String result;
        if (guessVal == random) {
            result = "Hit!";
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;

        } else if (guessVal < random) {
            result = "Low!";
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;

        } else if (guessVal > random) {
            result = "High!";
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;

        } else {
            return "error";

        }
    }

    public static void startGuessing() {

        int i = 0;
        do {
            guess();
            i++;

            } while (result != "Hit");

        System.out.println("That took you " + i + " guesses!");


    }
```

trying to pass result to the while test is throwing up a "cannot resolve symbol" error. I shall continue to google....